# RPM package won't install dependency

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild

I used rpmbuild to build an RPM package, however when I try to to install that RPM later on (with 'yum install' since it should take care of dependencies) I get the following error:

```
yum install package.rpm

Examining package.rpm: package
Error: Nothing to do
```

When I try to install it with 'rpm -i', I get this:

```
rpm -i package.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
        libzip5 is needed by package
```

My question is -- how come 'yum install' won't install the dependency?

If I try to manually install that required package (with `yum install libzip5`), I have no issues, but I really need yum to install it automatically with 'package.rpm'.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected if `package` is already present on your system. Even if it presented with a lower version.

On RHEL8+ you can use: `dnf install --best` which installs the latest version.

Or you can use `yum upgrade` which will explicitly ask for an upgrade and takes your package from the command line if it has a higher version.